# Suddenly I get the error "cannot read termcap database"

Tags: linux, macos, terminal

After switching from RVM to system ruby I keep getting this error.  It doesn't seem to be affecting anything, but pops up when I try to install a gem or use irb.  Any ideas on how to repair this?  This is on Mac 10.7.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found the answer here:

In Terminal I had to go to Preferences->Settings->Advanced, and change xterm-color256 to xterm-color.

Comment: That implies your system is missing the appropriate terminfo files for xterm-256color, and probably others. As of Mac OS X Lion 10.7, Terminal supports 256 colors and Background Color Erase (BCE), and is overall more compatible with modern xterm, so the default $TERM value is now xterm-256color. xterm-color is not recommended, as it represents an older branch of xterm that is not as functional. You might try installing Lion again or acquiring a copy of the missing terminfo files and placing them in /usr/share/terminfo. The xterm-256color terminfo files should be in `/usr/share/terminfo/78/`.

Comment: Did you do an upgrade install from 10.6.x to 10.7? Have you installed Xcode? (If so, which version?)

Comment: Loosely related: I had a problem where after installing xcode on OS-X lion my delete key no longer acted like backspace. In fact, in hitting delete the cursor would go forward one space visibly but back one space internally in the buffer. Very weird. The above fix fixed this for me.