# Rack Pow failed to start ENOENT

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, rack-pow

When trying to open any *.dev project exception raises:

```
Error: connect ENOENT
Error: connect ENOENT
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:892:19)
```

**pow log:**

```
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:30 GMT+0400 (MSK)] DEBUG nack worker 6521 spawned
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:33 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING Cannot read termcap database;
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:33 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING using dumb terminal settings.
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:87:in `eof?': closed stream (IOError)
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING   from /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:87:in `block (2 levels) in start'
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING   from /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `each'
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING   from /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:86:in `block in start'
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING   from /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `loop'
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING   from /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:66:in `start'
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING   from /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/lib/nack/server.rb:13:in `run'
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:39 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING   from /Users/nr/Library/Application Support/Pow/Versions/0.4.1/node_modules/nack/bin/nack_worker:4:in `<main>'
[Thu Nov 14 2013 12:18:40 GMT+0400 (MSK)] DEBUG nack worker exited
```

**versions:**

- pow 0.4.1
- ruby 2.0.0p247 (2013-06-27 revision 41674) [x86_64-darwin12.4.0]
- rails 4.0.1
- node v0.10.17 (also tested with v0.10.18)

**system:**

- OSX 10.9 (Mavericks)

**tryed:**

- re-installing Pow: doesn't help
- re-installing Node.JS: doesn't help
- downgrading to Pow 0.4.0 and 0.3.2: doesn't help
- downgrading Node.JS: doesn't help
- system restart: no luck

Also, issue on GitHub: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/422

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm getting this same issue: https://github.com/37signals/pow/issues/420

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like I've found a fix (for my case). I just commented this row in .powconfig:

```
#export POW_TIMEOUT=999999999
```

When this row is uncommented then server fails to start.
I'm not sure why exactly this happens but with commented row server works fine.
I suggest you to try default config. Now my log looks like this:

```
[Fri Nov 15 2013 17:24:29 GMT+0400 (MSK)] DEBUG nack worker 40864 spawned
[Fri Nov 15 2013 17:24:32 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING Cannot read termcap database;
[Fri Nov 15 2013 17:24:32 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING using dumb terminal settings.
[Fri Nov 15 2013 17:24:40 GMT+0400 (MSK)] DEBUG nack worker 40894 spawned
[Fri Nov 15 2013 17:24:43 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING Cannot read termcap database;
[Fri Nov 15 2013 17:24:43 GMT+0400 (MSK)] WARNING using dumb terminal settings.
```

Comment: I've just had this problem and your solution works. After I did this I set `export POW_TIMEOUT=86400` (24 hours) and that worked also.

Comment: The reason of this behaviour is that Pow multiplies POW_TIMEOUT by 1000 (1s). So the value 999999999 became 9999999990000 which affects nack in some way. Anyway I pleased that my solution worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Note that this error can also be caused by your browser trying to access a pow .dev page through https (just change it to http). Just for the reference of anybody else who happens to fall pray to that issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd check the value of $TERM in your shell. "echo $TERM"

Sounds like you've got a funky value in there, or are missing files for the value that you have in there.

See: [Suddenly I get the error "cannot read termcap database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066851/suddenly-i-get-the-error-cannot-read-termcap-database)

Comment: What does the TERM var have to do with this problem? Mine is set to `xterm-256color`.

Comment: You'll get "read termcap database" as an error if you have a value in $TERM that isn't valid/mis-spelled etc...